# upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx

we are facing issue in nginx while hitting the post request Advanced Rest Client.

Error message - upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream

nginx.conf file is :

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    upstream uic_entry {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:4005;
    }
    upstream mid_entry {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:4060;
    }
    upstream rule_entry {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:4070;
    }
    upstream spike_entry {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:5005;
    }
    upstream notification_entry {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:10039;
    }
    upstream oauth_entry {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:4000;
    }
        upstream check_entry {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:3000;
    }
     ## our http server at port 80
        server {
        listen      80;
        server_name xx.xx.xx.com;
      # redirect http to https
        rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        }
        ## Our https server at port 443
   server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  xx.xx.xx.com;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/xxx-server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/xxx-server.key;
    ssl_verify_depth 4;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503         http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        ignore_invalid_headers off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding  "";
        proxy_read_timeout 200;

    location ~\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        #root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        #return 503;
        proxy_pass          http://uic_entry;
    }

    location ~/(.*)/(v.*) {
    proxy_pass          http://mid_entry;
    }
    location /xxxx/ {
        proxy_pass          http://mid_entry;
    }

    location /templateservice/middleware/ {
    proxy_pass          http://mid_entry;
    }
        location /templateservice/trule/ {
        proxy_pass          http://rule_entry;
    }

    location /templateservice/security/ {
        proxy_pass          http://spike_entry;
    }

    location /checkAuthentication {
        proxy_pass          http://check_entry;
    }
    location /xxxx {
        proxy_pass          http://oauth_entry;
    }
     location /xxxx/client_register {
        proxy_pass          http://oauth_entry;
    }
     location /xxxx/access_token {
        proxy_pass          http://oauth_entry;
    }

    location / {
        #root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        #return 503;
        proxy_pass          http://uic_entry;
    }
    location /EmailService {
        #root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        #return 503;
        proxy_pass          http://notification_entry;
    }
    location /NotificationService {
        #root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        #return 503;
        proxy_pass          http://notification_entry;
    }
}

}
```

Please help us to fix this issue.

Comment: Probably you should fix upstream

Comment: Kindly guide me how to fix the upstream

Comment: I can't. Here upstream is one of `xx.xx.xx.xx:4070` and I have no idea what's behind this address. Are you sure they are http servers? May be they are fastcgi?

Comment: they are http servers... coded through nodejs

Comment: Check the headers upstream is sending by using any HTTP client (curl, postman, browser) directly to your upstream app. Can you paste them here? One of them is not valid. If it is a custom header, you might want to append "x-" before the header string. Also, I once sent non-standard HTTP status codes (more than 3 digits) and nginx would throw the same error.